# How to allow user to input new values in an if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I would like for someone to help me by telling me what code I should use in case the input number turns out to be for the second if or third if, if the user doesn't put the right amount (73-77) then id like the user to be able to type in a new value I can use... how do I do that please?

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int FahrToCels(int fahr)
        {

            int cel = (fahr - 32) * 5 / 9;
            return cel;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            Console.WriteLine("write down temprature: ");
            int fahrenheit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());            
            int celsius = FahrToCels(fahrenheit);                       
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . .");
            Console.ReadKey(true);

            do
                if (celsius >= 73 && celsius <= 77)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("now it works ");                    
                }
                else  if (celsius < 72)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("");                   
                }

                else if (celsius > 77)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    
                }
            while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that `celsius` is in `[73..77]` range you can try

```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
     int fahrenheit;
     int celsius;

     // Keep asking user until (s)he enters a valid celsius value
     while (true) {
       Console.WriteLine("Skrive in Temperaturen: ");

       // check if value a valid integer, and not say "bla-bla-bla"
       if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out fahrenheit)) {  
         Console.WriteLine("Not an integer value, please, try again");

         continue;
       }

       // fahrenheit is a valid integer value, we can compute corresponding celsius...
       celsius = FahrToCels(fahrenheit);

       // ... and validate the celsius value then
       if (celsius < 73) 
         Console.WriteLine("Too low temperature (below 73 degree Celsius)");
       else if (celsius > 77) 
         Console.WriteLine("Too high temperature (above 77 degree Celsius)"); 
       else
         break; // celsius is valid integer value in [73..77] range   
     } 

     // From now on celsius contains integer in [73..77] range
     Console.WriteLine("Now it works");

     Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . .");
     Console.ReadKey(true);
   }
```

Comment: ah i'll ive it a try. Thank you very much for your time and answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

There are a few major issues with what you have. Attached is working code for what I believe you are looking for, though in your ifs you have Celsius range in the 70s when the point of your Fahrenheit to Celsius converter turns the value into Celsius which would lie in the 20s range.

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int FahrToCels(int fahr)
        {

            int cel = (fahr - 32) * 5 / 9;
            return cel;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int celsius;
            int fahrenheit;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Skrive in Temperaturen: ");
                fahrenheit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                celsius = FahrToCels(fahrenheit);

                Console.Write("Presifs any key to continue . . .");
                Console.ReadKey(true);


                if (celsius >= 22 && celsius <= 28)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("now it works ");
                    //Insert whatever here
                    break;

                }
                else if (celsius < 22)
                {

                    //Something to tell them they need to retry


                }

                else if (celsius > 28)
                {

                    //Something to tell them they need to retry

                }
            }
            while (celsius >= 22 && celsius <= 28);

        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend changing the range on your `ifs` to the values you want the user to input, and also provide the user with some error/retry statement in your `elseifs`. Also would recommend instead of having two `elseifs` just use else. Also would remove that stupid `readkey()` in my opinion.

If you have any questions to my answer leave them in the comments.

Comment: thanks, ill try out the first code and if its not really what i hoped for ill try out your code, anyways your answer is very much appriciated ty so much :)